# How can I delete rows with empty objects in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object, drop

I have a dataframe with a column "A" and the data type of this column is object. I want to remove all rows from the dataframe that have empty cells in the column A. What I have tried so far:

`df.dropna(axis=1, subset=["A"])`

Comment: `df[df.A.ne('')]` if empty values are strings or `df.dropna(subset=["A"])` if empty values are `NaN`s

Comment: Both versions do not work for me

Comment: ok, so what are real empty values? Check `print (df['A'].tolist())`

Comment: My output is [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

Comment: `df[df.A.ne(' ')]` or ``df[df.A.str.strip().ne('')]`` should working - there is one space instead empty space.

Comment: I thought the field had "" as empty cells, but they are filled with " " (with a space). That is why my original solution with 
``df.drop(df[df.A== ""].index)``
did not work. With:
``df.drop(df[df.A== " "].index)``
it has now worked!

Comment: df[df.A.str.strip().ne('')] also worked, thank you for the hint!